# Exit the finder sync extension on exiting the Cocoa App

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a Cocoa app with a finder sync extension.

I want this extension to be available only when my application is running.

How do I quit the Finder Sync extension when i am exiting the main cocoa app.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Even if you kill the process of FSE, Finder will restart it. Afaik, only user can disable the extension in System Preferences.

Comment: @mixtly87 That's right. I found that out during the course of development. Thank you.

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/204004#204004